# How do I add ads to my local site which I host on my local area connection of my college campus?

Tags: html, ads, revenue

I have a website that runs in my college LAN and I want to add some revenue making ads. Its a website that offers downloads and tech blogs. However I have no interest of putting it up online and just host it locally. How do I do so?

What I have tried:

I have gone through different ad sites but I didnt get any proper results.

Comment: Does your college allow you to use their network for commercial purposes?